# How long did the first implementation of javascript take?

Tags: javascript, history

I'm curious: how many days, weeks, months or years did it to code the first stable version of JavaScript?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: I believe there's a good history of this in [Coders at Work](http://www.codersatwork.com/brendan-eich.html), Brendan Eich's chapter.

Comment: [Please try to do some research before posting questions](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> JavaScript, not to be confused with Java, was created in 10 days in May 1995 by Brendan Eich, then working at Netscape and now of Mozilla.

From [W3C's A Short History of JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript).

Comment: How on earth can someone create an entire programming language in 10 days?

Comment: By being a well motivated and very talented person with a looming deadline? Remember this was the very first version of JS. It was much, *much* simpler than what we have today. Still quite an incredible achievement.

Comment: Link now redirects to wikipedia which doesn't contain the relevant story. Here's a wayback link: http://web.archive.org/web/20130126071121/http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript